# Typed DataSet - InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dataset, .net, typed

I've got a typed dataset. I bind the data with a binding source to a form with arround 200 textboxes, dataedits and so on. Everything works fine with one exception:

In my database I have empty DateTimes (DBNull.Value). And when they get bound to a DateEdit-Control, I get the following exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException' occurred in myTestDLL.dll
```

I tried to change the NullValue-Property in the DataSet-Desinger to something else as 'Throw Exception', but it doesn't work for a DateTime. For other types like Integer or String it works fine.

I dont know a nice solution (right now I fill the empty dates with some dummy date and make it invisible in the DateEdit-Control, but this is very uncool) and I hope to find some help here.

It seems that many people got the same problem but I didn't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not just skip  if test fail ?

```
if dMyDate is dbnull.value then 'skip, msgbox, set to date.minValue, whatever
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But at which point I should check that? If the controls get unbound values, your solution would work, but I don't see a way with a binding source behind it. Any other idea?